# Getting started with XMLPullParser

Tags: xmlpullparser

I am trying to use XMLPullParser but I cannot find any useful tutorials. Based off of the instructions on http://xmlpull.org/  I need to download an implementation of XMLPullParser as a jar file and then add it to my class path.  However I cannot find any link to any jar file that works.  Does anyone know where I might be able to find  a jar file I can  download.

Thanks

Comment: There are .jar files for download if you click "Download Implementation". What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here it is for you.

From the [official doc](http://www.xmlpull.org/impls.shtml) :

> **XmlPull API Implementations:**
>
> 1. XNI 2 XmlPull
> 2. XPP3/MXP1
> 3. KXML2

Here i use KXML2.

**Steps :**

1. Download KXML2 jar file from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kxml/).
2. Create a new java project

[image]

3. Create a new class

[image]

4. Right click the java project -> Properties -> Java Build path -> Libraries -> Add external jar's -> Add downloaded `kxml2` jar file.

[image]

5. Java code

   ```
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.StringReader;
   import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
   import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
   import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

   public class XmlPullparserBasic {
   public static void main (String args[]) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
   {
       XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
       factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
       XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
       xpp.setInput( new StringReader ( "<foo>Hello World!</foo>" ) );

       int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

       while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
            System.out.println("Start document");
        } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
        } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
        } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
            System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
        }
        eventType = xpp.next();
       }

       System.out.println("End document");

     }

   }
   ```

**Output :**

[image]

Hope it helps!